# Is mounting of docker.sock required for host monitoring from within docker container?

Tags: docker, linux-containers

Does it require to mount `docker.sock` for a docker container to monitor host files( look for **changes** in a file *say logs*) from within the container?

If so, why?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you need/want to do. If you just want to check for changes in some files on the host, it's better to just mount the folder as a volume in the container.

Comment: Are you monitoring Docker on the host or something else?